# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0

Tags: c#, winforms

I was starting to work on my application which I haven't touched for about a month and when I run the application and try to save a change I get the following error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types,
>   Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.":"Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"}    System.Exception
>   {System.IO.FileNotFoundException}

I have no idea why this error is all of a sudden showing up cause the last time I ran this application, I never encountered this problem so I'm at a loss where this is coming from. It happens on the Context SaveChanges event but when the error shows up I can hit the run button again and it will continue on as if nothing happened.  After I do that, all successive attempts to save will work without showing the error but if I restart the application, it will show up again.  My application is a Windows Form app using .NET Framework and Entity Framework 4 and the database is Sql Server 2005.  Any thoughts on what could be causing this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Were there any updates installed in the meantime to this package or to visual studio? I would remove and re-add the reference to that package.

Comment: do you have SQLSysClrTypes installed ?

Comment: Papa,  there were no updates installed to my knowledge and I have no reference to the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types in my project.  I can only assume it's used by the Entity Framework, possibly in System.Data.Entity cause it's occurring on the SaveChanges method of the entity.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where all of a  sudden my reports were not coming up.

So i wen to my web.config for the project where your reports view is.

Paste this code as is in the assemblybinding tags.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
    <!-- <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" /> -->
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```